# Textbox Autorefresh after insert data to database

Tags: c#, oracle11g, textbox

i have a textbox in C# and a insertbutton , i have allready show Max+1 in textbox  from my databse column ItemId

> ```
> OleDbDataAdapter _adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT MAX(ItemId)+1  FROM TableItem", con);
>             DataTable _datatable = new DataTable();
>             _adapter.Fill(_datatable);
>             textBoxInsert.Text = _datatable.Rows[0][0].ToString();
> ```

now textbox show successfully may data 
but when i have going to insert to  data insert successfully and refresh grid   and can not auto refresh   text box which  i have show max+1
 i have following   insertion command

```
>  OleDbDataAdapter adp3 = new OleDbDataAdapter("INSERT INTO
> TableItem(ITEMID,ITEMNAME,UNITID,CATEGORYID,ITEMSTATUS,SUPPLIERID)VALUES('"+textBoxInsert.Text+"','"+textBoxItem.Text+"','"+comboBoxUnitId.Text+"','"+comboBoxCategory.Text+"','"+textBoxStatus.Text+"','"+comboBoxSupplier.Text+"')",
> con);
>            adp3.SelectCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
>            
>            autorelode();//Call Autoload Method
>          
>              OleDbDataAdapter _adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT MAX(ItemId)+1  FROM TableItem", con);
>             DataTable _datatable = new DataTable();
>             _adapter.Fill(_datatable);
>             textBoxInsert.Text = _datatable.Rows[0][0].ToString();
```

**but can not auto refresh my data in textbox.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create  method then call the method in insert button

> ```
> private void auto()
>         {
>             OleDbDataAdapter adp= new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT MAX(ChallanNo)+1  FROM TablePurchase", con);
>             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
>             adp.Fill(dt);
>             ChallanNo.Text = dt.Rows[0][0].ToString();
>             con.Close();
>         }
> ```